# Display forms in a panel by a button on another form

Tags: c#

I have made forms using c# and they are opening in the same panel when I click my buttons on the menu,
How can I make my other forms to open in the same panel when I click on the button on the child form.

Comment: We need some code or minimal running example to help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.